# Swift: how to type cast a protocol into a specific one?

Tags: xcode, swift, casting, sprite-kit, protocols

I have a simple code as the following. The class MySprite (to display a red rectangle) is extended from class SKSpriteNode and protocol ISprite:

```
import SpriteKit

protocol ISprite {
    func doSomething()
}

class MySprite: SKSpriteNode, ISprite {
    var scence: SKScene?

    init(theParent: SKScene) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300))
        self.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        scence = theParent
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func doSomething() {
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var mySprite:SKSpriteNode = MySprite(theParent: self)
        self.addChild(mySprite)
    }
}
```

The code can be compiled and run well. However, after changing the type of mySprite from SKSpriteNode into ISprite as the following, I cannot cast / downcast it back into SKSpriteNode:

```
        var mySprite:ISprite = MySprite(theParent: self)
        self.addChild(mySprite as? SKSpriteNode!)
```

The swift compiler says error: "Type SKSpriteNode does not conform to protocol ISprite"

Any idea about error and solution? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addChild expects an SKNode with doesn't conform to ISprite. It can also take a subclass of SKNode e.g. SKSpriteNode. When mySprite is an SKSpriteNode Swift can guarantee that addChild will get an SKSpriteNode. Casting mySprite to SKSpriteNode fails because SKSpriteNode doesn't conform to ISprite so Swift can't guarantee that it will be an SKSpriteNode. You can cast mySprite to MySprite which is a subclass of SKNode so addChild can take it:

```
addChild(mySprite as MySprite)
```